# ServiceMIX exception handling

Tags: java, web-services, exception, apache-camel

I have a simple route:

```
public class PartnerRoute extends SpringRouteBuilder
{

    @Value("${comm.async.req.incoming.queue}")
    private String reqInputQueue;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception
    {
        onException(Exception.class)
        .to("activemq:queue:wrongMessages");

        from("cxf:bean:partnerService")
        .log("PartnerData arrived")
        .to("activemq:queue:" + reqInputQueue);

    }
}
```

As you see, the start point is a CXF webservice.
The WS defined in camel-context.xml

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="partnerService" 
    address="http://${comm.host}:${comm.port}/cxf/PartnerService" 
    serviceClass="esb.ws.partner.service.PartnerService" />
```

I would like to handling the CXF exception. (Someone calls the WS with wrong data.)

I have got this error, when I call the WS with wron structure:

```
2015-02-26 16:16:44,901 | WARN  | org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain | org.apache.cxf.cxf-api | (LogUtils.java:452) | Interceptor for {http://service.partner.ws.esb.ivir.tsm.hu/}PartnerServiceService#{http://service.partner.ws.esb.ivir.tsm.hu/}startMessageProcessing has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"messageFilterx"). Expected elements are <{}messageFilter>,<{}hash>,<{}priority>,<{}referenceNumber>,<{}responseRequired>,<{}requestDate>,<{}messageType>,<{}consumer>,<{}requestor> 
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:881)[139:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:2.7.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:702)[139:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:2.7.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:160)[139:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:2.7.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:192)[135:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.7.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)[135:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.7.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)[135:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.7.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.serviceRequest(JettyHTTPDestination.java:355)[157:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty:2.7.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:319)[157:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty:2.7.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:65)[157:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty:2.7.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1088)[63:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1024)[63:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)[63:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)[63:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)[63:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)[63:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)[63:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)[63:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)[63:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)[63:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)[63:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)[63:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)[63:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)[63:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)[63:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)[63:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)[:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"messageFilterx"). Expected elements are <{}messageFilter>,<{}hash>,<{}priority>,<{}referenceNumber>,<{}responseRequired>,<{}requestDate>,<{}messageType>,<{}consumer>,<{}requestor>]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:425)[84:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.1.1_2]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:362)[84:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.1.1_2]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:339)[84:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.1.1_2]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.doUnmarshal(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:842)[139:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:2.7.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.access$100(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:101)[139:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:2.7.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder$2.run(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:870)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_51]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:868)[139:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:2.7.11]
    ... 25 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"messageFilterx"). Expected elements are <{}messageFilter>,<{}hash>,<{}priority>,<{}referenceNumber>,<{}responseRequired>,<{}requestDate>,<{}messageType>,<{}consumer>,<{}requestor>
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:642)[84:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.1.1_2]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:254)[84:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.1.1_2]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:249)[84:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.1.1_2]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:116)[84:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.1.1_2]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.childElement(Loader.java:101)[84:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.1.1_2]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.childElement(StructureLoader.java:243)[84:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.1.1_2]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:478)[84:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.1.1_2]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:459)[84:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.1.1_2]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleStartElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:242)[84:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.1.1_2]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:176)[84:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.1.1_2]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:360)[84:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.1.1_2]
    ... 31 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"messageFilterx"). Expected elements are <{}messageFilter>,<{}hash>,<{}priority>,<{}referenceNumber>,<{}responseRequired>,<{}requestDate>,<{}messageType>,<{}consumer>,<{}requestor>
    ... 42 more
```

I set up the "onException" but nothing happened.

Could you help, how can I handling that exception?

Thank you!

Feri

Comment: Have you checked if your message is sent to the `activemq:queue:wrongMessages` queue? The exception is not set to be handled so it is returned to the caller and therefore seen in the log.

Comment: Yes, I checked. I know, each exception appears in the log, regardless of what the processing route. My problem that, the message was not at fault queue.

Answer (score 1):

Its a chicken and egg situation. Camel's error handler using onException or errorHandler is during routing. But that entails the consumer is able to accept the incoming message and create a Camel `Exchange` instance and start route the message.

From the stracktrace this is not the case, as Apache CXF fails to do so. Some Camel components support bridging from the consumer errors to Camel error handler using `consumer.bridgeErrorHandler=true` option. Not sure if that is the case with CXF.

Comment: Hi Clause! Thank you your answer, but it doesn't work. I understand, this error hapens in CXF, but how can I handling the exception, in this case? The route is "predefined", so the normal try-catch doesn't work. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the Exception to go any further, you need to mark it as *handled*.

```
onException(Exception.class)
    .handled(true)
    .to("activemq:queue:wrongMessages");
```

Comment: I think it is a misunderstanding. I don't mind the exception. My problem that the message doesn't arrive into the 'wrongMessages' queue.

Comment: Are you sure the onException block is triggering - can you add a log statement there?

Comment: No, the onException doesn't triggered. Thi si my problem!

Comment: Okay. Make sure the `onException` is defined *above* the route code (I usually put them right at the top), and that no other `onException` block somewhere else overrides it.

Comment: Thank you your help! :-) You can check my code. And this project contains only this route definition. (This is the entry point to the ESB processing.) If you check the Clause's mesage, that contains the root of the problem, I think.